# Difficulties with Binary Search Tree with Generics Implementation

Tags: java

I'm having an issue with implementing this BinarySearchTree listed below. For some context, I'm creating a binary search tree based off of an interface that requires generics and a comparable key.I think that there is a logic error in the code that is stumping me and it's in the insert method in the BinarySearchTree, but I'm not 100% sure.

Below is the class for my Node, which is used in my BST.

```
public class MyNodeClass<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value>{
private Key key;
private Value value;
private MyNodeClass<Key,Value> left = null;
private MyNodeClass<Key,Value> right = null;

public MyNodeClass(Key key, Value val)
{
    this.key = key;
    this.value = val;
}

public void setKey(Key key){
    this.key = key;
}

public void setValue(Value value){
    this.value = value;
}

public Key getKey(){
    return this.key;
}

public Value getValue(){
    return this.value;
}

public void setLeft(MyNodeClass<Key, Value> l){
    this.left = l;
}

public void setRight(MyNodeClass<Key, Value> r){
    this.right = r;
}

public MyNodeClass<Key,Value> getLeft(){return this.left;}

public MyNodeClass<Key,Value> getRight(){return this.right;}

public int compareTo(Key that){
    return(this.getKey().compareTo(that));
}
```

}

---

```
public class MyBinarySearchTree<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value> implements BinarySearchTree<Key,Value>  {

private MyNodeClass<Key, Value> root;

public MyBinarySearchTree(){
    root = null;
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return root == null;
}

@Override
public Value insert(Key key, Value val) {
    MyNodeClass<Key,Value> newNode = new MyNodeClass<Key,Value>(key,val);
    newNode.setKey(key);
    newNode.setValue(val);
    if(root==null){
        root = newNode;
        return(newNode.getValue());
    }
    else{
        MyNodeClass<Key,Value> current = newNode;
        MyNodeClass<Key,Value> parent;
        while(true){
            {
                parent = current;
                if(current.compareTo(key) == 1)
                {
                    current = current.getLeft();
                    if(current == null)
                    {
                        parent.setLeft(newNode);
                        return parent.getLeft().getValue();
                    }
                }

                else if(current.compareTo(key) == -1){
                    current = current.getRight();
                    if(current == null)
                    {
                        parent.setRight(newNode);
                        return parent.getRight().getValue();
                    }
                }

               else{
                    if(current.compareTo(key) == 0){
                        current.setKey(key);
                        current.setValue(val);
                        return current.getValue();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public Value find(Key key) {
    MyNodeClass<Key, Value> current = root;
    while (current.compareTo(key) != 0)
    {
        if (current.compareTo(key) == 1)
        {
            current = current.getLeft();
        } else {
            current = current.getRight();
        }
        if(current == null)
            return null;
    }
    return current.getValue();
}

@Override
public Value delete(Key key) {
    MyNodeClass<Key,Value> current = root;
    MyNodeClass<Key,Value> parent = root;
    boolean isLeftChild = true;

    while(current.compareTo(key) != 0) {
        parent = current;
        if (current.compareTo(key) == 1) {
            isLeftChild = true;
            current = current.getLeft();
        } else {
            isLeftChild = false;
            current = current.getRight();
        }
        if(current == null)
            return null;
    }

    if(current.getLeft() == null && current.getRight() == null) {
        if (current == root) {
            root = null;
        } else if (isLeftChild) {
            parent.setLeft(null);
        } else{
            parent.setRight(null);
        }
        return current.getValue();
    }

    else if(current.getRight() == null)
    {
        if(current == root) {
            root = current.getLeft();
        }
        else if(isLeftChild) {
            parent.setLeft(current.getLeft());
        }
        else{
            parent.setRight(current.getLeft());
        }
        return current.getValue();
    }

    else if(current.getLeft() == null)
    {
        if(current == root)
            root = current.getRight();
        else if(isLeftChild)
            parent.setLeft(current.getRight());
        else
            parent.setRight(current.getRight());
        return current.getValue();
    }

    else
    {
        MyNodeClass<Key,Value> successor = getSuccessor(current);

        if(current == root)
            root = successor;
        else if(isLeftChild)
            parent.setLeft(successor);
        else
            parent.setRight(successor);
        successor.setLeft(current.getLeft());
        return current.getValue();
    }
}


@Override
public String stringLevelOrder() {
    return(LevelOrder(root));
}


private MyNodeClass<Key,Value> getSuccessor(MyNodeClass<Key,Value> deleteNode)
{
    MyNodeClass<Key,Value> successorParent = deleteNode;
    MyNodeClass<Key,Value> successor = deleteNode;
    MyNodeClass<Key,Value> current = deleteNode.getRight();

    while(current != null)
    {
        successorParent = successor;
        successor = current;
        current = current.getLeft();
    }

    if(successor != deleteNode.getRight())
    {
        successorParent.setLeft(successor.getRight());
        successor.setRight(deleteNode.getRight());
    }
    return successor;
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    MyBinarySearchTree<Double, MyStudent> BST = new MyBinarySearchTree<Double, MyStudent>();
    MyStudent myStud1 = new MyStudent();
    MyStudent myStud2 = new MyStudent();
    MyStudent myStud3 = new MyStudent();
    MyStudent myStud4 = new MyStudent();
    MyStudent myStud5 = new MyStudent();

    myStud1.init("Clarise", 1.1);
    myStud2.init("Christopher", 1.2);
    myStud3.init("John", 1.3);
    myStud4.init("Chloe", 1.4);
    myStud5.init("Goo", 1.5);

    System.out.println(BST.insert(myStud1.getGPA(), myStud1));
    System.out.println(BST.insert(myStud2.getGPA(), myStud2));
    System.out.println(BST.insert(myStud3.getGPA(), myStud3));
    System.out.println(BST.insert(myStud4.getGPA(), myStud4));
    System.out.println(BST.insert(myStud5.getGPA(), myStud5));

    System.out.println("Delete Key 1.0: " +BST.delete(1.3));
    System.out.println("Delete Key 1.4: " +BST.delete(1.4));
    System.out.println("Is Empty?: " +BST.isEmpty());
    System.out.print("Find 3.9: "+  BST.find(3.9));
}
```

}

---

The result of the main is the following:

{Clarise:1.1}

{Christopher:1.2}

{John:1.3}

{Chloe:1.4}

{Goo:1.5}

Delete Key 1.0: null

Delete Key 1.4 null

Is Empty?: false

Find 3.9: null

---

I'm not entirely sure what the issue is and I've had some help from others, however they can't find the problem. Hoping that someone else can see something that we don't see.

Answer (score 0):

In your `insert` method, after you've checked that `root` is not `null`, you are inserting `newNode` into the `newNode` instead of inserting it into the `root`.

This:

```
MyNodeClass<Key,Value> current = newNode;
MyNodeClass<Key,Value> parent;
```

Should be:

```
MyNodeClass<Key,Value> current = root;
MyNodeClass<Key,Value> parent;
```

P.S. any kind of testing would show you the problem with your `insert` within a minute. You could write a `size()` method and see that your inserts are not working, you could write a `toString()` method and see the state of the tree, finally you could debug.

Comment: Yup that was it completely, thank you very much. Completely overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyNodeClass<Key,Value> current = newNode;
```

There is problem here. 
If a tree is not empty, then your "current" should begin at root node. What you done is insert "newNode" to "newNode".

Change the code to be:

```
MyNodeClass<Key,Value> current = root;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue right there, I just overlooked it completely.